# TypeError: Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I am writing a web app in react and as soon as I use reactdate picker in my code ,it simply breaks giving me the error stated above .
Adding these two lines breaks my webapp and throws an error .

```
import {SingleDatePicker} from 'react-dates';
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';
```

I have react-dates installed in package.json file but I don't understand as how to fix this and move forward ?

Comment: Check the docs on the date picker.. Does it require any theme? The error basically means you are doing trying to get the property `theme` on a `null` object, like `null.theme`. So you have to find what the `null` is .

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Readme](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates), you may want to add this `import 'react-dates/initialize';` to root of your application

Comment: This worked .My bad for not not going to the correct place .